# How Can I create an item on an android listview when I click on a button

Tags: android, android-listview, listviewitem

I'm an android beginner, so I need some help.

Right now I'm developing an app in where on an Activity, I create several buttons, all of them represents a different item, for example: apples, pears, etc. When I click or press one of those buttons I need that an item, that is represented for the button, will be added in other Activity on a ListView. At the end, the activity shows me all of the items added on the listview.

For now, I only have two java classes and two xml files.

One of the xml files, contains the ListView and the other the buttons.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please post what you have done so far

Comment: posting code might be good.

Answer (score 0):

Question is a little too vague to understand what your problem is. A `ListView` simply represents a way to display a list of items through an `Adapter`. At the high level, all you need to do is modify this list of items whenever you click on one of the buttons and call `Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to let the list view know that the list of items has changed.

Comment: I want to add an item, but when I press the button, that represent an item. This button is in one activity, and the list on another. At the beginning, I design the app with a select box items, but I thought that is not an easy form to the user, because they have to pass through different activities to look again what they selected. Instead, I want the user can see what they select on a list, avoiding passed through all app activities.